# Conditional distribution of order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)}$ be the order statistics of a set of $n$ independent uniform $(0,1)$ random variables. Find the conditional distribution of $X_{(n)}$ given that $X_{(1)}=s_1,X_{(2)}=s_2....,X_{(n-1)}=s_{n-1}$

I need to find: $P[X_{(n)}\le x_n| X_{(1)}=s_1,X_{(2)}=s_2....,X_{(n-1)}=s_{n-1}]$ which is equal to: $${P[X_{(n)}\le x_n, X_{(1)}=s_1,X_{(2)}=s_2....,X_{(n-1)}=s_{n-1}]\over P[X_{(1)}=s_1,X_{(2)}=s_2....,X_{(n-1)}=s_{n-1}]}$$

but I have no idea how to compute the above probability and also I don´t know how to use the fact that the variables are uniform and independent. I would really appreciate if you can help me with this problem

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can work with the CDF as well but there is an easier way. Recall that for a random sample of size $n$ from a uniform (0,1) distribution, the joint density for all the order statistics is given by

$$f_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)},\ldots,X_{(n)}} \left(x_{(1)},x_{(2)},\ldots, x_{(n)} \right)=\begin{cases} n!  & 0<X_{(1)}<X_{(2)}<\ldots<1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

This is just all the possible permutations of the random variables. This density will
serve as the numerator of your fraction. We need to integrate out the greatest order statistic so as to get the joint density of the remaining order statistics. Thus

$$f_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)},\ldots,X_{(n-1)}} \left(x_{(1)},\ldots,x_{(n-1)} \right)=\int \limits_{x_{(n-1)}}^{1} n!\ \mathrm{dy} =n!\left(1-x_{(n-1)}\right)$$

Putting these two together, gives the conditional probability you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! @JohnK

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the conditional distribution of $X_{(n)}$ simply uniform on $(s_{n-1},1)$?

Comment: I have the same question: $X_{(n)}$ is the largest isn´t it?

Comment: I thought it was...perhaps conventions vary.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $0< s_1< \cdots < s_{n-1}< s_n < 1$.

Let $S=\{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_{n-1}\}$, let $X=\{X_1, \ldots X_n\}$, let $X_\ast$ be an arbitrary member of $X$

$\mathsf P[X_{(n)}\le s_n| X_{(1)}=s_1,X_{(2)}=s_2....,X_{(n-1)}=s_{n-1}] = \dfrac{\mathsf P[X_{\ast}\leq  s_n \mid X\setminus \{X_\ast\} = S]}{\mathsf P[X_{\ast}> s_{n-1}\mid X\setminus \{X_\ast\} = S]}$

The conditional probability that the $n$-th smallest number in the list is not greater than $s_n$ when given fixed values for all smaller numbers in the list, is the probability that the unfixed result (which ever one it is) is not greater than $s_n$ given that it is greater than $s_{n-1}$.

Since all members in the list have an identical independent uniform distribution, this means $\mathsf P[X_{(n)}\le s_n| X_{(1)}=s_1,X_{(2)}=s_2....,X_{(n-1)}=s_{n-1}] = \dfrac{\mathsf P[s_{n-1}<X_{\ast}\leq  s_n ]}{\mathsf P[X_{\ast}> s_{n-1}]} = \dfrac{s_{n}-s_{n-1}}{1-s_{n-1}}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I just don´t understand why is it that $X_{*}$ is greater than $s_{n-1}$?

Comment: Because we want it to be the $n$-th smallest member of the list, which is greater than the $(n-1)$-th smallest member of the list. @user128422

Answer (score 1):

Given all $n-1$ values of $\mathbf{x}$, the probability of the largest one being smaller than $x_n$, i.e. $P(X_{(n)}\leq x_{n}|\cdots)$ is equal to $1-P(X_{(n)}> x_{n}|\cdots)$. The key point is that if $X_{(n)}$ is larger than $x_{n}$, due to the order statistic we also know that it is larger than all other $x_i$, $i<n$. This says that $$1-P(X_{(n)}> x_{n}|X_{n-1}=x_{n-1},\cdots)=1-P(X_{(n)}> x_{n},X_{n}>x_{n-1},\cdots)$$ $$=1-P(X_{(n)}> x_{n})P(X_{n}>x_{n-1})P(X_{n}>x_{n-2})\cdots$$ $$=1-(1-U(x_n))(1-U(x_{n-1}))(1-U(x_{n-2}))\cdots$$

where $U$ is the uniform c.d.f. The second equality is due to independency.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Seyhmus: one last thing: the independence also apply when its the same random variable?

Comment: @user128422 every random variable is dependent to itself. If you randomly take some samples and without any connection beween the samples, then the corresponding random variables are independent. This is usually given in the questions.

Comment: So in the last part $X_n$ is independent to itself given by the problem?

Comment: No. $X_n$ is fully dependent on $X_n$. But I dont have this assumption when I say separate the joint distribution to its marginals.

Comment: @user128422 btw in your question $P[X_n=s_n,...]$ the denominator, is equal to $0$.

Comment: The other answers (correctly, in my view) agree that the answer is uniform on $(s_{n-1},1)$. It seems you confused $X_j$ and $X_{(j)}$ somewhere along the way. It's not clear to me why $X_n$ appears at all, and in the condition you have $X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}$ instead of $X_{(n-1)}=s_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition of conditional density function $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$, then
$$f_{X_{(n)}|X_{(1)}\cdots X_{(n-1)}}(x_n|x_1,\cdots ,x_{n-1})=\frac{f(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n)}{f(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_{n-1})}=\frac{n!\times 1}{\int_{s_{n-1}}^1 n!f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2)\cdots f(x_n) dx_n }=\frac{1}{1-s_{n-1}}$$. So, the conditional distribution equals to $\int_0^a \frac{1}{1-s_{n-1}} dx_n=\frac{a}{1-s_{n-1}}$ . We can also say this conditional distribution is uniform on $(s_{n-1},1)$ .